# Don't show Cell if it's nil or something like that

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a CoreData project and 2 Entity which names are MainList and Football..

MainList entity has 3 attriubutes ;

listName;
listFavoritePlayer
listPlayerValue

Football entity has 2 attributes;

teamName;
teamBestPlayerValue

I add attributes from AddFootball viewcontroller. like ;

```
addTeam.teamName = _txtTeamName.text;
addTeam.bestPlayerValue = _txtBestPlayer.text;

addMainList.listName = _txtListName.text;
addMainList.favoritePlayer = _txtFavoritePlayer.text;
addMainList.playerValue = _txtPlayerValue.text;
```

I fetched MainList from my tableviewcontroller.

```
cell.textlabel.text = mainList.listName;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = mainList.playerValue;
```

It's OK for now. In this way I keep team attributes to my Football entity and I can show them in my tableviewcontroller with MainList.

**But.. There is a problem here ;**

When I want to add only FavoritePlayer in my Add FootballViewController with this code.

```
addMainList.favoritePlayer = @"Messi";
```

MyTableView cell comes with empty. Because I didn't add mainList.listName and mainList.playerValue. But I want to add favoritePlayer without listName and playerValue for fetch from another viewcontroller.

I think I need a if else statement or another think.

if cell.textLabel.text = nil; Don't show

OR

if selectedRow. listName = nil ; Don't show the Cell.

OR

delete them if empty or nil before show Cell.

I just want only 1 attributes except listName or playerValue.

Answer (score 1):

The displaying of cells should be based on a datasource that you determine beforehand.  I would first filter the data source to remove the objects that do not contain a mainList.listName and mainList.playerValue.  And then ... reload the table.